# failed to push project to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

```
&&@Macbook-Pro~/Documents/workspace/RoR/rails_projects/first_app$ git push -f
 heroku master


Counting objects: 151, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (124/124), done.
Writing objects: 100% (151/151), 97.10 KiB, done.
Total 151 (delta 54), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Detected Rails is not set to serve static_assets
       Installing rails3_serve_static_assets... done
-----> Configure Rails 3 to disable x-sendfile
       Installing rails3_disable_x_sendfile... done
-----> Configure Rails to log to stdout
       Installing rails_log_stdout... done
-----> Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.7
       Unresolved dependencies detected; Installing...
       Using --without development:test
       /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:7:in `instance_eval': /disk1/tmp/build_3poyinkzfabqd/Gemfile:3: syntax error, unexpected tLSHFT, expecting $end (SyntaxError)
       <<<<<<< HEAD
         ^
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:7:in `evaluate'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:17:in `build'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `definition'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:225:in `install'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
        from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
       FAILED: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler

To git@heroku.com:blazing-night-8821.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:blazing-night-8821.git'
```

Comment: Have you had a merge conflict in your Gemfile recently?

Comment: why are you pushing with the `-f` flag to heroku ? That's push with force

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is wrong with your Gemfile on line 3

```
/disk1/tmp/build_3poyinkzfabqd/Gemfile:3: syntax error, unexpected tLSHFT, expecting $end
```

Comment: Does bundle update work locally?  If so post your Gemfile here